# Expresso-store - Comma in quantity field

Tags: expresso-store

It seems that if a user enters a comma in the quantity field (as in 2,000) the system ignores the figures after the comma and will add just the amount before the comma (ie '2').

Is there a way to prevent this happening?

(version 2.4.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use HTML5 form validators such as

```
<input type="number" name="item_qty">
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend-o, I would make use of this addon's extension hooks. You would want to create an extension that hooks to one of these:

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html

Like this one:

```
store_order_item_add_start
```

And then parse and modify the quantity value of the `form_params` variable array where the item quantity value most likely lives. Regular Expression out the commas, or even easier, string replace with an empty value!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution by any means, but you can also use JS to prevent anything but numbers and decimal points from being entered.  I do this on CC forms.

```
<script>
$('#fieldID').on('keypress', function(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
</script>
```